# When the water falls, the area of the water narrows

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

[image]
When the water falls, the area of the water narrows.
[image]
I want to make the water fall in a straight line, not in the middle.

What settings should I adjust?

Only the size of the inflow cube was adjusted, but no other settings were adjusted.

[image]

If i do this, the size of the inflow tube falls in a straight line,
[image]

If i reduce the size of the inflow tube, the water drops like this.

[image]

Comment: I uploaded the file. but
It is the same as the initial setting and only adjusted the size of the inflow cube.

Comment: If you google for example images of water running from a tap, it is quite common that the water curves in after the pressure is gone which forces it to use the full diameter of the aerator. Water is cohesive.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

with initial velocity of z: -3 and resolution to 64, i got this:

[image]

AFAIK it is "physical" correct that water does at least a bit narrowing.

I hope this helps a bit.

Comment: Thank you for answering my question

Comment: if my answer was satisfying for you, please click on the checkmark left of my answer.thx.

Comment: I didn't know it wasn't checked. Sorry.